# Show hyperlinks only when user is loggedin

Tags: themes

I am a newbie in wordpress.My problem is that I want to make an option for the admin in my theme, so that when admin creates a post and insert a hyperlink on the post there should be an option to make the hyperlink invisible to the users who are not logged in. How can it possible please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter hook to replace the hyperlink with login url.
following snippet should do the trick.

Update: this function should check if the user is logged in or not (my bad i forgot to add that)

```
add_action( "the_content", "restrict_url_in_post_content" );
function restrict_url_in_post_content() {
    $loginUrl = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="some-class">%s</a>', wp_login_url( get_the_permalink() ), __( "You need to login to view this link", "text_domain" ) );
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        $the_content = preg_replace( "/<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/", $loginUrl, $the_content );
    return $the_content;
}
```

**Update:**

Use following *shortcode* to have same effect on specific content.

Uses: `[restricted]<a href="#">url</a>[/restricted]`

```
function restricted_content( $atts , $content = null ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'show_login'      => '1',
            'message'         => __( "You need to login to view this", "text_domain" ),
            'login_redirect'  => get_the_permalink(),
        ),
        $atts,
        'restricted'
    );
    $loginUrl = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="some-class">%s</a>', wp_login_url( $atts["login_redirect"] ), $atts["message"] );
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $content;
    } else if( $atts["show_login"] == 1 ) {
        return $loginUrl;
    } else {
        return $atts["message"];
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'restricted', 'restricted_content' );
```

Comment: Keep only one version of the code.

Comment: thank you very much, but with this code all the url is showing in visible, i want to customised for a url...

Comment: i added shortcode snippet you can use that for same effect in specific content.