# Changing the redirection of a restricted url

Tags: redirect, login, urls, wp-redirect, template-redirect

I've almost finished setting up a website as a complete laymen and i used a function posted on here that allows hyperlinks to be only visible to logged in users. The function works completly fine, all i need it to do now is redirect to my custom login page instead of the default wordpress login and my lack of knowledge makes it hard to formulate the question properly to find a solution on google.

The function i copied:
[Show hyperlinks only when user is loggedin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251965/show-hyperlinks-only-when-user-is-loggedin)

Uses: `[restricted]<a href="#">url</a>[/restricted]`

```
function restricted_content( $atts , $content = null ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'show_login'      => '1',
            'message'         => __( "You need to login to view this", "text_domain" ),
            'login_redirect'  => get_the_permalink(),
        ),
        $atts,
        'restricted'
    );
    $loginUrl = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="some-class">%s</a>', wp_login_url( $atts["login_redirect"] ), $atts["message"] );
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $content;
    } else if( $atts["show_login"] == 1 ) {
        return $loginUrl;
    } else {
        return $atts["message"];
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'restricted', 'restricted_content' );
```

I've the feeling this is easily solved so i apologize for what might be a stupid quesiton but i'd realy appreaciate your help! Thank you.